# R - Current timestamp with milliseconds precision

Tags: r, timestamp, milliseconds

How do I get current timestamp with milliseconds precision?

I tried the option of setting `digits.secs=3` but, couldn't get the milliseconds part.

```
> op<-options(digits.secs=3)
> format(Sys.time(),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%s")
[1] "2015-01-07 22:44:51.1420650891"
> library(lubridate)
> format(now(),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%s")
[1] "2015-01-07 22:45:15.1420650915"
```

I need the milliseconds precision specifically as that is how the rest of the system is set-up.

Comment: How about `format(Sys.time(), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg Yes, that worked, thanks ! It also worked with `%3S` for the seconds bit.

@Henrik, yes, a possible duplicate - I was too focused on generation than parsing. Sorry!

Comment: @henrik I don't believe that this is actually a duplicate, as the linked question is about parsing text strings and this is formatting timestamps.  While these are related, there must be a better question to choose as a duplicate.